# JBoss JNDI Binding Manager - maximum length of value?

Tags: xml, jboss, jndi

I'm using the technique described [here](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/Server_Configuration_Guide/Additional_Naming_MBeans-JNDI_Binding_Manager.html) to register string values on the JNDI tree via an XML file deployed to JBoss.

This is working fine for my system constants (URLs and the like).  However I am also trying to register the contents of a file which has been encoded to a Base64 string.  The file is fairly large (about 400k), so the resulting string is very long.

When I try to deploy the XML file to JBoss, I get the following error:

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/usr/local/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/customers-service.xml" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
```

Is this likely to be because I am exceeding the maximum allowable length for the string value and hence it is only reading it to a certain point?

Comment: Did you try passing type="java.io.File" and as path to file as a value?

Comment: I have tried that (after reading your comment), but I don't think it actually puts the file on the JNDI tree as there is no error even if the file name is complete wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation of the JNDI Binding Manager, the unmarshalling is actually peformed by the JBossXB (JBoss XML Binding) framework:

> The JNDI binding manager service
>   allows you to quickly bind objects
>   into JNDI for use by application code.
>   The MBean class for the binding
>   service is
>   `org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr`.
>   It has a single attribute,
>   `BindingsConfig`, which accepts an XML
>   document that conforms to the
>   `jndi-binding-service_1_0.xsd` schema.
>   The content of the `BindingsConfig`
>   attribute is unmarshalled using the
>   JBossXB framework.

But the documentation doesn't mention any limitation regarding the `BindingsConfig` or the [JBossXB](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/JBossXB) framework. And to be honest, I don't really get why there would be such a low limit (the size is pretty decent for a JDNI object but well, we are far from Java limits for a `String`).

So, if your are sure that your file is well formed and valid (and you should confirm that programmatically outside of JBoss), maybe you could proceed to some dichotomous testing: try with the 1/2 of the string size, then 3/4, etc. But this won't really solve your issue, it will just help the community, especially if you log something in [JBoss Jira](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBAS). And maybe you'll get more helpful hints there. This is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
> ```

If the XML document itself is for certain valid, then this problem look like a buffer overflow or an incorrect interpretation of the content length which caused a shortened line without an end-tag being returned. This is likely a bug in the SAX parser in question. Which one are you using? I would recommend [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/) in its latest version.